# In "Your Name", why does anyone let the scammers get away without calling the police?

Tags: your-name

There is the scene in *Your Name* where Okudera intervenes as the scammers say there is a toothpick in their pizza.

Why do they let the scammers get away like that? Is that for convenience as calling the police on them would make a scene or something else I am missing?

Comment: Based on reading someone's review, looks like the scammers are holding a cutter knife, and in fact, do cut Okudera's skirt before leaving?

Comment: @AkiTanaka that is true. However the restaurant staff are not aware that they do have a knife. Okudera even admits that "they were definitely scamming us". Then why they let them to get away with it?

Comment: I haven't watched the movie, so I can only guess based on reading [someone's review (in Japanese)](https://himote.plus/blogs/view/46047). However, based on the transcription, looks like the original Japanese dialog is using the term ["claimer"](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC), not ["scammer"](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A9%90%E6%AC%BA%E5%B8%AB). The nuance might be lost in translation, but since I don't have enough context, I'll let anyone else who has watched and understood the scene to provide their answer first...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignoring these things is how most such bussinesses are run. If you called the police, it'd cause a scene that would likely deter customers (and annoy the ones already there). You'd lose more money than you would get from the jerks in the end. That's not to mention the possibility of them deciding to cause havoc and break furniture or even assault the staff, or the fact that the scammers could simply deny your claims.

Losses like these are usually budgeted for and written off as a loss, with the police only getting called if the scammers make it a regular habit (where the cost of their repeated scams outweight the loss of causing a scene).